# Mathematica Compute Time Is Extremely Long (Integrate simple function with parameter scan)

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I was wondering if you can help. I have a set of equations I need to solve for a list of parameters; entering each parameter value and solving anew each time is simply not economical.

I found a way to vary the parameter and have Mathematica solve the equation, but the calculation now takes extremely long and does not even return a solution. Here is my code below (very simple):

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What can be done to make the calculation faster?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please put properly formatted code in your question. Read the *help* for instructions.

Comment: Still no proper *Mathematica* code. :(

Answer (score 2):

Combined symbolic and numeric calculation can be hard to deal with. You may do the symbolic part first and then do the substitution, or do the pure numeric integration `NItegrate` many times.

```
Integrate[(n3 + 
s^2/(2 r))*(c e n)/(g r^(2/3) (s/lb (end - beg) + beg)^(4/3)), {s, 0, lb}][[1]]
```

Output:

```
(3 c e lb n (beg^(
   1/3) (5 beg + 6 beg^(2/3) end^(1/3) + 3 beg^(1/3) end^(2/3) + 
     end) lb^2 + 
  10 (beg^(2/3) + beg^(1/3) end^(1/3) + end^(
     2/3))^2 n3 r))/(10 beg^(
1/3) (beg^(2/3) + beg^(1/3) end^(1/3) + end^(2/3))^3 end^(1/3)
 g r^(5/3))
```